# Logic in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, onclick, nested

I'm trying to build a javascript button that will have this logic:

```
IF(Type = "A" AND (Field1 == "" OR Field2 == ""))
IF ELSE (Type = "B" AND (Field1 == "" OR Field2 == ""))
ELSE {script for approval}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is:

1. Write the IF statements continuously with only one ELSE statement at the end
2. Write the logic for (Type = "A" AND (Field1 == "" OR Field2 == "")) (nest the OR statements then compare it with the first one using AND)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like homework?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried?

Comment: Is the single `=` intentional for `Type`?

Comment: It's 'else if' not 'if else'

Comment: the expression (Type = "A") always returns true, after setting the value of Type to "A". I assume you want Type == "A" or Type === "A" which are logical comparisons. IF, ELSE IF and ELSE need to be in lower case, (if, else if, else). As well as AND and OR ... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Do neither of the if statements actually do anything if they are true? Your code seems to only run something if neither of the expressions are true.

Comment: You should have enough information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your if and's and Or's check this out
also try using this to help yourself test...

http://jsfiddle.net/Egli/2a4apuwm/1/

```
//Set up your variables to test here
var Type = "A";
var Field1 = "";
var Field2 = "";

//Test conditions
if(Type == "A" && (Field1 == "" || Field2 == ""))
{
    alert("In: Condition 1");
}
else if(Type == "B" && (Field1 == "" || Field2 == ""))
{
    alert("In: Condition 2");
}
else
{
    alert("script for approval!");
}
```

Ohh and make sure u run the fiddle i sent you (the link i sent you) then you can use it to test your logic edit it etc :)

Comment: Actually it's a validation check for a custom object I built in Salesforce. What the code will do is check if the required fields per Type is/are filled out.

Comment: Good stuff, perhaps this tool can aid you in testing your logic... all the best

Answer (score 0):

```
if (any expression, the answer will be changed to a booleen true or false) {
  /* do something */
  if (expression B) {
     /* do something */
  } else {
     /* nested if else applies to expression B THE LAST IF STATEMENT* */
  }
} else if (Expression C) {
     /* do this is the main Expression was false but Expression C was true */
  } else {
     /* this block runs if Expression C was false, 
     which also means the main expression was false 
     Indentation for readability is a question of style. 
     Here it is indented to show ownership*/
}
```

Your logic is OK, your syntax is bad; Javascript is case sensitive. And the declairation, Type = "A" always returns A ... MyType = Type = "A" /* MyType is "A" which converts to true*/